How often does systemd journal collect/read logs from sources
I have a program that generates several logs per second and I want to track these logs in real time using the journal, but it seems there is delay for the journal to collect/read logs from the source. I tried to find if there is an option to control this delay, but it seems not. The option SyncIntervalSec isn't what I'm looking for -- it just defines how often journal write its log into files and I don't think the journal only shows the logs that were already written into files because the delay is shorter than the default value(5m) for sure.
How often does the journal collect/read logs from its sources? Moreover, how does journal collect/read logs from sources?

"... it seems there is delay": on what evidence? Are you sure you've drawn the correct conclusion?

@user207421 I've used print() to generate the logs in Python and according to accepted answer, there is buffer in print(). I didn't measure the exact time but it takes more than 20s to display the logs.


So how often does journal collect/read logs from sources? Moreover how does journal collect/read logs from sources?

Mostly, it does not collect logs from sources. Logs arrive at the journald daemon in real-time (approximately), just as they used to be provided to syslogd in real-time – whenever programs call syslog() they write their messages to a Unix socket that the daemon is listening on, and the OS immediately wakes the daemon up indicating data available.
Likewise, whenever systemd services that are set up for "stdout logging" write() to their stdout pipe, the OS immediately delivers that data to journald (which is on the other end of the pipe).
As for programs that write to their own log files – journald does not collect those at all. (With the kernel logs being perhaps the only exception, but even those are streamed from /dev/kmsg in real time – there is still no interval for collecting them.)

If it appears that a service's stdout logging doesn't reach journald, the most common problem is buffering within the service; e.g. a fwrite() in C or a print() in Python will generally be buffered by libc until some 4-8 kB of messages is gathered, and only then does it get written out through the pipe in a single burst. If the write() isn't being done at all then there is nothing journald could collect. (You don't notice this when running programs interactively in a terminal because the runtimes treat a tty specially.)
In such cases, assuming you're the author of the program, you can either have it flush the output after every message, or set its stdout layer to line-buffered mode (which it would use if stdout were a terminal), or write your messages to stderr which typically remains line-buffered by default... or switch to the real syslog() interface, which lets you specify message priorities as well.

If you're writing in Python, you can do either:
# Use the Unix syslog interface:
import syslog
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "Hello!")

# or make stdout line-buffered (i.e. each line will be automatically flushed):
sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)

# or flush buffered stdout data after every write:
print("Hello!", flush=True)

# Equivalent to:
# sys.stdout.write("Hello!\n")
# sys.stdout.flush()


If you're writing in C using libc stdio, you also have the same options:
/* Use the Unix syslog interface: */
#include <syslog.h>
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Hello %s!", name);

/* or make stdout line-buffered, during initialization: */
setlinebuf(stdout);

/* or flush buffered data after every write */
fprintf(stdout, "Hello!");
fflush(stdout);

/* or use the BSD-style functions */
#include <err.h>
warnx("Hello %s!", name);


In case you're using a program written by someone else and don't have the source code of – first check whether it can be switched to syslog mode (which is never buffered).
Often programs that write their logs to stdout can be "fixed" by preloading the libstdbuf.so library; this only works for those that use libc stdio buffering:
$ myapp | cat
$ stdbuf -oL myapp | cat

Environment=LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
Environment=_STDBUF_O=L
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myapp




Excellent explanation! Yes i make logs using print() in python and that's why there is huge delay in my journal. I didn't know there is buffering. Thank you!

@Ihave10fingers: Right, in that case – I should've included this in the post – you should be doing either print(..., flush=True) or sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffered=True). (Don't use stdbuf, that's only for programs that you don't have the source code of.)

There's no regular "checking" here; journalctl simply waits until new data is available and immediately processes it (it uses the epoll kernel mechanism for that, which tells the kernel that a thread wants to sleep until data is available and woken up as fast as possible as soon as there is – where talking single-digit milliseconds here, at most).
The delay you see is probably caused by the pager you're using to look at journalctl's output. Try this:

open a terminal, run

journalctl -e -f --no-pager --output=short-precise
#          ^  ^  ^          ^
#          |  |  |          |
#          \------------------- scroll to end of journal
#             \---------------- follow new messages coming in
#                \------------- don't use the `less` pager you're probably using
#                            \- print timestamps with high precision


open another terminal, and run

while [[ $? ]]; do logger -d $(date '+time %S.%N') && date '+reference %S.%N' && sleep 1; done
done

in that, which runs an infinite loop (until you ctrlc-kill it, or an error occurs) of logging the current time.

See how close the timestamps are: the delta between log entry and log entry timestamp is in the order of 3 ms for me, and the delta between printed "reference" time and log entry timestamp in the order of 3 ms, too, so we're talking about a window of 6 ms.

Note that I don't know how your program logs. That method itself might be buffered, or it might do bad things like trying to connect to a syslog daemon for every. single. entry., which would take longer than 3 ms to fail.
